# Asynchronous Form in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

I am new to ColdFusion and I was hoping for some advice. I created a super basic shopping list program and I was wondering how I can update the list without having to refresh the page. I thought about importing the data from my DBMS into an array and just displaying the content of that array. I was able to do everything besides actually displaying every item within the array. I am getting an error: `Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values.`

Here is my code:

```
<body>
    <cfquery datasource="ESC-ADD-TECH" name="items">
        SELECT *
        FROM items
        ORDER BY itemDesc ASC
    </cfquery>

<div id="myDIV" class="header">
    <h2>My Shopping List</h2>
    <cfform  id="new_item">
    <cfinput type="text" name="updateinfo" placeholder="Item..." required="true" />
      <input name="submitButt" type="submit" class="addBtn"></input>
    </cfform>

    <cfset itemsArray = arrayNew(1)>
    <cfset arrayAppend(itemsArray, #items#)>

    <cfif structKeyExists(form, "submitButt")>
    <cfset arrayAppend(itemsArray, #updateinfo#)>

    <cfquery datasource="ESC-ADD-TECH">
    INSERT INTO items(itemDesc) VALUES('#updateinfo#')
    </cfquery>


    </cfif>
</div>

          <cfoutput query="items">  
    <ul>
        <li>#itemsArray#</li>
    </ul>   
          </cfoutput>

</body>
```

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to S.O. If you're new to the site, it's different than a forum.  1) To avoid this question being [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) as too broad" best break it up into multiple, smaller, questions 2) Be sure to include the JS code you've tried so far and a description of the result/errors 3. As far as the "bug", that's not a bug.  Sounds like you're using `<form method="POST" ...>`. POST operations usually change data. When you refresh/reload on a form that was already submitted, the browser asks for confirmation to be sure you really want to submit it twice.

Comment: @Ageax thank you for your comment. I apologize for being too broad in my approach. I have updated the post so hopefully things are a bit better from there. Thank you for the information

Comment: (Update) From a UX perspective, the best way is to use JS, but .. just to be sure I understand, when you said "...really wish I can just use javascript, but not able to unfortunately." does that mean you're not sure *how* to use it or requirements forbid using javascript (which would be odd, but... ;) ?

Comment: @Ageax project requirements forbid it sadly

Comment: Unfortunately, without JS or some client side language, there's no other way to reload the list without submitting the form. Even if you preloaded the data into JS arrays (not ideal, but works) you'd still need JS manipulate the page contents (or DOM).

Comment: Do you know why they forbid it, because that's unusual these days? With most good libraries, a feature degrades gracefully. In other words, it works for browser that support it and those that don't fall back on a plain form submit

Comment: @Ageax (some background) I am in the early learning phases and I've recently got a job offer as a junior dev for a company that solely uses coldfusion. It's a processing company and everything was coded in coldfusion 15 years ago and they have no intention on changing, thus forcing me to learn coldfusion. My background is predominately React and Javascript so it's a learning curve for sure. This question was for my "trial test" to see if they want to take me on full time or not.

Comment: Well, CF is just like any other server side web app language (asp, asp.net, php, etc..). It doesn't know anything about client side code. The app server parses the CFML (php, asp.net, whatever language) and spits back the HTML/CSS/JS that code generated. There's no reason the CFML code can't include javascript, unless the client explicitly said don't.  If they did, then yeah, the only way to refresh the list is by resubmitting the page. From a coding standpoint, it's actually a lot simpler ... though it does make for a very 1990's UX ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177134/discussion-between-ageax-and-g-rose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Too long for comments....)

## ;tldr

CF is just like any other server side web app language (asp, asp.net, php, etc..). It doesn't know anything about client side code. The app server parses the CFML (php code, asp.net, whatever language...) and spits back the HTML/CSS/JS that code generated. So there's no reason your CFML code can't include javascript, unless the client explicitly said don't use it. If they did, then yeah, the only way to refresh the list is by resubmitting the page. From a coding standpoint, a self-posting form is simpler, but does make for a very 1990's UX ;-)

## Suggestions:

It sounds like you are well versed in javascript, so you should have no problem with manipulating the DOM via ajax. However, if you were going to use a self-posting form instead, a few comments about the current CF code:

1. Strictly a style preference, but separating query and "view" (or display) code keeps things more readable IMO.
2. In order to display any newly added items, the code must perform the INSERT first, *then* the SELECT query.
3. The 'complex object...' error is due to the INSERT query treating an array (complex) like a simple value (string, date, number). CF doesn't know how to implicitly convert the complex array '#updateinfo#' into a string. That said, you don't actually need an array at all (see #4)
4. Your form only contains a single input field, so no need for arrays. Just insert the single value directly. Keep in mind it's a good practice to always use cfqueryparam to protect against sql injection. Plus its other benefits like validation and performance. Also, always scope variables to avoid ambiguity. Example, use `FORM.updateinfo` instead of just `updateinfo`
5. Although `<cfform>` works, it (and associated controls like `<cfinput>`, etc..) have fallen out of favor in recent years. Primarily because it's baked into CF making it difficult to update or customize behavior.
6. It's good to get into the habit of knowing when to use or not use pound signs. Most people are surprised at how often they're NOT needed. There are a few exceptions, but generally they're only required when either:

   a. A variable is enclosed in quotes. Example:
   b. A variable is enclosed within `<cfoutput>` tags
7. If you're from a JavaScript background, you might prefer [cfscript](https://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/coldfusion/cfscript/) over cfml (tags). As of CF11+, almost anything you can do in cfml, can be done in cfscript.

**Revised Script**

```
<!--- 1. Add new items --->
<cfif structKeyExists(form, "submitButt")>
    <cfquery datasource="NameOfYourDSN">
      INSERT INTO items(itemDesc) 
      VALUES(
        <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.itemDesc#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
      )
    </cfquery>

</cfif>

<!--- 2. After inserting, get new list of items --->
<!--- Avoid SELECT * (select all) and only return the columns you need --->
<cfquery datasource="ESC-ADD-TECH" name="items">
    SELECT *
    FROM items
    ORDER BY itemDesc ASC
</cfquery>

<!--- 3. View Code --->
<html>
<body>
    <div id="myDIV" class="header">
        <h2>My Shopping List</h2>
        <form id="new_item" method="POST" action="nameOfYourScriptHere.cfm">
            <input type="text" name="itemDesc">
            <input name="submitButt" type="submit" class="addBtn">
        </form>
        <cfoutput query="items">  
        <ul>
            <li>#itemsArray#</li>
        </ul>   
        </cfoutput>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Anonymous down voter,  please leave a comment on what you think can be improved.

Comment: Doesn't the form require an action attribute since I'm not using a cfform tag? (I'm not the anonymous person btw)

Comment: Required? Technically, no. Most browsers will default to the current script if an "action" is omitted. That said, yes, it's a good practice to supply one. It's okay, I didn't think the anonymous person was you :-)  Usually people leave a comment on what they think could be improved, but not everyone does. Since both the question and answer were downvoted, I suspect they didn't read the history (or comments) and decided it was too broad. *shrug* Sometimes that's the way it goes on S.O.

Comment: I’ve had that happen before as well. Thanks again!